# Part-time job along with an internship in University to manage expense?

Tags: working-visas, germany, study, internship

I am enrolled to a international internship in TU-Chemnitz, Germany, as its a compulsory internship (with work permit) towards my degree completion. Its unpaid also. Can I do a part-time/Minijob to manage my expense?

Comment: This presumably depends on whether your work permit allows employment other than in connection with your internship.  Does your work permit have any limitations?

Comment: There is nothing specified on work permit. I on an internship visa, unfortunately, it unpaid. i need a source of income, my internship is full-time as of right now.

Comment: The answer depends on your visa. We can't answer this without knowing what kind of visa/permit you have.

Comment: But I also imagine you had to prove the ability to financially support yourself before getting the visa/permit, no?